# Processing Extent in ArcPy with polygon to raster

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, extents, multi-criteria-analysis

I want to do a multicriteria analysis. To do that I have buffered layers that I want to convert to rasters, but I want to set a processing extent and make so where the buffer area is gets value 1 for each layer (meaning the value is 2 if 2 buffered layer is at the same spot) and 0 if there is no buffered layer there.

How do I do this in ArcPy?

[image]

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb'

mxd_path = r"C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Projekt.mxd"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)

    
tennis = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Tennis'
pulka = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Pulka_val'
rest = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Restuarants'
vatten = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Vatten'
gym = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Gavle_projekt.gdb\Gym'
alko = r'C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Alkohol.shp'

def make_layer(path_shp, layername):
    if arcpy.Exists(layername):
        arcpy.management.Delete(layername)
    return arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path_shp,layername)

def re_project(in_layer, out_layer):
    if arcpy.Exists(out_layer):
        arcpy.management.Delete(out_layer)
    arcpy.management.Project(in_dataset= in_layer, out_dataset=out_layer, out_coor_system= "3006") #Sweref99TM

def buffer(in_layer, out_layer):
    if arcpy.Exists(out_layer):
        arcpy.management.Delete(out_layer)
    return arcpy.analysis.Buffer(in_features=in_layer, out_feature_class=out_layer, buffer_distance_or_field= '1000 Meters')

tennis_lyr = make_layer(tennis, "Tennis_layer")
pulka_val = make_layer(pulka, "Pulka_val_layer")
restaurant_lyr = make_layer(rest,"Restaurant_layer" )
vatten_lyr = make_layer(vatten, "Vatten_layer")
gym_lyr = make_layer(gym, "Gym_layer")
alko_lyr = make_layer(alko, "Alko_lyr")

re_project(restaurant_lyr,"restaurants_layer_reproj")

# Buffra lagren
buffer(tennis_lyr, 'Tennis_buff')
buffer(pulka_val, "Pulka_buff")
buffer("restaurants_layer_reproj", "res_reproj_buff")
buffer(vatten_lyr, "Vatten_buff")
buffer( gym_lyr, "Gym_buff")
buffer(alko_lyr, "Alko_buff")

arcpy.env.extent = "C:\Users\daniel\Studier\Applikationsutveckling\Projekt\Gavle\Demdata2\Demdata.tif"

arcpy.conversion.PolygonToRaster(in_features, value_field, out_rasterdataset, {cell_assignment}, {priority_field}, {cellsize}, {build_rat})
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have posted? Do you get error messages?

Comment: Well the code works, i just dont know how to make a processing extent and make my polygons to raster where i get value 1 for the cells that have a buffer in it and value 0 for " here is no buffered layer" within the extent.